# Перезапись анимаций сворачивания/разворачивания активити

Tags: android, анимация, activity

Как презаписать(заменить кастомными) анимации сворачивания и разворачивания активити? Уже все что можно перерыл. overridependingtransition помогает только при создании и закрытии активити, однако при нажатии кнопки Home или при вызове moveTaskToBack(), активность все равно обрабатывается со стандартной анимацией. Возможно ли вообще заменить стандартную анимацию сворачивания и разворачивания активити?

Comment: Тут смотрели? http://stackoverflow.com/a/25878811/3212712

Comment: Это не подходит. Тут, опять же, рассматривается вариант закрытия (finish()) активити, а мне нужна анимация, после нее активити должно работать в фоне.

Comment: Сильно сомневаюсь что анимация сворачивания по кнопке Домой может быть как то переопределена. Её просто нелогично делать не стандартной для системы.

Comment: Я тоже так думаю. Я сделал этот пост как последнюю надежду.